# Cancelar todas las subscripciones y tareas asyncronas sin usar useEffect

Tags: reactjs

Tengo este error, ya he buscado hasta el cansancio distintas soluciones por varias páginas de internet incluída stackoverflow y no logro una que aplique para mi caso,

Resumiré lo mayor posible para no expandir mucho el tema e ir directo al grano solo espero encontrar a alguien que pueda ayudarme

Uso una librería Stepper para secuenciar los pasos

- En el paso 1 : Confirmo la compra
- En el paso 2 : Elijo el método de pago en este caso solo tarjeta
- En el paso 3 : Lleno los datos de la tarjeta para crear el pago con
  una librería llamada Stripe que permite realizar pagos con tarjetas
  de crédito o débito
- En el paso 4 : Es el paso final que se mostrará solo cuando el pago
  se haya realizado completamente

El problema es que en el paso 3 para crear el método de pago con código extraído de la documentación de Stripe se usa llamadas asyncronas con await  y este mismo es el que me genera el error, cuando paso al paso 4 yo muestro un nuevo componente y desaparesco los componentes del paso 3,, al hacer esto recibo el error de que estoy tratando de actualizar un estado en un componente que ya no existe , sin embargo al momento que actualizo mi estado del Stepper para que me lleve al último paso ,, yo ya no realizo ninguna actualización de estado más , y aún asi recibo el mensaje y vi que lo que está ocacionando este problema es la llamada await y me pide que limpie todas las subscripciones y tareas asyncronas antes de pasar a un nuevo componente , entonces necesito saber como limpio esta llamada asyncrona

En el paso 3
Cabe decir que todo el proceso de validar los campos del formulario de los datos de la tarjeta y al momento que se empieza a crear el método de pago lo hace en una función handleSubmit llamada por un botón ,,, es por eso que la solución o llamada asyncrona mediante el useEffect no es aplicable para mi caso, yo necesito una forma de limpiar todo directamente en el mismo handleSubmit

Aqui dejo mi código resumido :

constante de estado global, aqui mismo creo mi estado del Stepper :

```html
const useStateGlobal = () => {
    const [steps] = useState(
        [{
            title: 'Confirmar Compra',
            href: 'http://example1.com',
            onClick: (e) => {
                e.preventDefault()
                console.log('onClick', 1)
            }
        }, {
            title: 'Seleccionar tipo de pago',
            href: 'http://example2.com',
            onClick: (e) => {
                e.preventDefault()
                console.log('onClick', 2)
            }
        }, {
            title: 'Detalles de pago',
            href: 'http://example3.com',
            onClick: (e) => {
                e.preventDefault()
                console.log('onClick', 3)
            }
        }, {
            title: 'Compra Finalizada',
            href: 'http://example4.com',
            onClick: (e) => {
                e.preventDefault()
                console.log('onClick', 4)
            }
        }]
    );

    const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState(0);
   
    return {
        steps,
        currentStep,setCurrentStep
    }
};
```

Ahora este es el componente del Stepper :

```html
export const Confirmar_Paquete_Stepper = () => {  
        
        const { steps, currentStep, setCurrentStep } = useBetween(useStateGlobal);
        const buttonStyle = { background: '#E0E0E0', width: 200, padding: 16, textAlign: 'center', 
        margin: '0 auto', marginTop: 32 };

        const onClickNext = (e) => {           
            let valor = (currentStep == null || currentStep == 0 )  ? 1 : currentStep+1;           
            setCurrentStep(valor);
        }

         const onClickBack = (e) => {
             let valor = (currentStep == null || currentStep == 0) ? 1 : currentStep - 1;
             setCurrentStep(valor);
         }

        if (currentStep == 0) {
        return (           
               <div id="contenedor-stepper-compra-paquete"> 
                   <Stepper steps={steps} activeStep={currentStep}  />
                <Confirmar_Paquete />
               </div>
        );
        }
        else if (currentStep == 1) {
        return (
               <div id="contenedor-stepper-compra-paquete">
                   <Stepper steps={steps} activeStep={currentStep} />
                   <Seleccionar_Tipo_Pago_Paquete />     
                <div style={buttonStyle} onClick={onClickBack}>Volver</div>
               </div>
        );
        } else if (currentStep == 2) {
            return (
                <div id="contenedor-stepper-compra-paquete">
                    <Stepper steps={steps} activeStep={currentStep}  />

                    <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
                        <CheckoutForm2/>
                    </Elements>
                    <div style={buttonStyle} onClick={onClickBack}>Volver</div>
                </div>
        );
        }   
          else if (currentStep == 3) {
              return (
                  <div id="contenedor-stepper-compra-paquete">
          
                      <Stepper steps={steps} activeStep={currentStep}  />
                      <Finalizar_Compra_Paquete />
                      <div style={buttonStyle} onClick={onClickBack}>Volver</div>
                  </div>
            );
        }  
};
```

Ahora el componente CheckoutForm2

```html
const CheckoutForm2 = () => {    
    const { steps, currentStep, setCurrentStep, token, datos_paquete_seleccionado, setDatos_paquete_seleccionado, camposDatosTarjeta, setcamposDatosTarjeta, formErrors, setformErrors, errores_servTarjeta, seterrores_servTarjeta,
            paseValidacionFormTitularTarjeta, setpaseValidacionFormTitularTarjeta,
            paseValidacionFormCorreoTarjeta, setpaseValidacionFormCorreoTarjeta,
            paseValidacionFormTarjeta, setpaseValidacionFormTarjeta,
            paseValidacionFormFechaExpTarjeta, setpaseValidacionFormFechaExpTarjeta,
            paseValidacionFormCvcTarjeta, setpaseValidacionFormCvcTarjeta,
            paseValidacionFormCiudadTarjeta, setpaseValidacionFormCiudadTarjeta,
        paseValidacionFormCodigoPostalTarjeta, setpaseValidacionFormCodigoPostalTarjeta
       } = useBetween(useStateGlobal);
    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();
    const titularTarjetaRegex = RegExp(
        /^[A-Za-z\s]+$/
    );
    
    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            
        };
    }, []);

    const HandleValidar = async (event) => {
        Aqui borre todo el código, pero simplemente valido cada campo del formulario por el evento onChange , que             es el que llama a esta función 
    }

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        Aqui es donde está todo mi código que se ejecuta cuando presione el botón de click que llamará a handleSubmit

        event.preventDefault();        
        const { titular_tarjeta, correo_tarjeta, ciudad_tarjeta, codigo_postal_tarjeta } = event.target;  
        
        Aqui dejaré solo un ejemplo de como valido cada campo de mi formulario , por ejemplo aqui valido el campo del         titular de la tarjeta
        
        //TITULAR TARJETA
        if (titular_tarjeta.value.length < 3) {           
            setformErrors(prevState => ({ ...prevState, titular_tarjeta: "Ingrese mínimo 3 caracteres"
         }));
            seterrores_servTarjeta(prevState => ({ ...prevState, titular_tarjeta: "" }));
            setpaseValidacionFormTitularTarjeta("NO");            
        }
        else if (!titularTarjetaRegex.test(titular_tarjeta.value)) {            
            setformErrors(prevState => ({ ...prevState, titular_tarjeta: "Formato de nombres inválido" 
         }));
            seterrores_servTarjeta(prevState => ({ ...prevState, titular_tarjeta: "" }));
            setpaseValidacionFormTitularTarjeta("NO");
            
        }
        else if (titular_tarjeta.value.length > 22) {
            setformErrors(prevState => ({ ...prevState, titular_tarjeta: "Ingrese maximo 22 caracteres" 
        }));
            seterrores_servTarjeta(prevState => ({ ...prevState, titular_tarjeta: "" }));
            setpaseValidacionFormTitularTarjeta("NO");
        }
        else {
            setformErrors(prevState => ({ ...prevState, titular_tarjeta: "" }));
            seterrores_servTarjeta(prevState => ({ ...prevState, titular_tarjeta: "" }));
            setpaseValidacionFormTitularTarjeta("SI");            
        }


        if (!stripe || !elements) {
            // Stripe.js has not yet loaded.
            // Make sure to disable form submission until Stripe.js has loaded.
            return;
        }
        
        if (paseValidacionFormTitularTarjeta == "SI" && paseValidacionFormCorreoTarjeta == "SI" &&                           paseValidacionFormTarjeta == "SI" && paseValidacionFormFechaExpTarjeta == "SI" && paseValidacionFormCvcTarjeta == "SI" && paseValidacionFormCiudadTarjeta == "SI" && paseValidacionFormCodigoPostalTarjeta == "SI")
        {    
            const cardElement = elements.getElement(CardNumberElement);
            const { error, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
                type: 'card',
                card: cardElement,
                billing_details: {
                    email: camposDatosTarjeta.correo_tarjeta,
                    name: camposDatosTarjeta.titular_tarjeta,
                    address: {
                        city: camposDatosTarjeta.ciudad_tarjeta,
                        country: 'PE',
                        postal_code: camposDatosTarjeta.codigo_postal_tarjeta,
                    }
                },               
            });

            if (error) {                
            } 
            else 
            { 
             setCurrentStep(3);                   
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <div id="contenedor-detalles-tarjeta">
            <Container component="main" maxWidth="md" justify="center">
                <label className="detalles-tarjeta-titulo">
                <Typography >
                    <span >Detalles de tarjeta</span>
                </Typography>
            </label>
            <form id="realizar-pago-visa" onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>

           Aquí he borrado porciones de código , pero solo es la creación de los campos del formulario de pago

         <Button type="submit" className="confirmar-orden" name="confirmar_orden" disabled= 
         {!stripe} variant="contained" color="primary">Confirmar orden</Button> 
         </form>
         </Container>
        </div>
    );
}
```

- 0 es el paso 1
- 1 es el paso 2
- 2 es el paso 3
- 3 es el paso 4

como verán, con setCurrentStep(3); paso al último paso del Stepper que sería el componente final y desaparezco los componentes de Element y el CheckoutForm2 que son del paso anterior, es ahí donde recibo el error a causa del await stripe.createPaymentMethod({ ... y dice que estoy intentando actualizar un estado en un componente que ya no existe, sin embargo cuando ocurre setCurrentStep(3); yo ya no actualizo nada más y no entiendo por que recibo el error, entonces creo que el error se refiere al await y pide que debo limpiar también la tarea asyncrona del await y no sé como hacerlo , debo limpiar todo mediante el mismo handleSubmit, sin usar useEffect ya que para mi caso eso no aplica .

Finalmente dejaré una imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]